# How can I convert Java Strings to MySQL datatype?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to convert some string values from Java into MySQL datatypes, I have tried using the datatype `varchar`, but the values I am passing over are HTML codes of a webpage, and they are too large for that datatype. If I have a string, that is an HTML code webpage, and I want to store it in a MySQL database, what datatype can I use? I tried changing the datatype of my column in MySQL to 'TEXT' and other datatypes, but I get this error, which I think is a problem because I am trying to insert a string value which cannot be inserted to those datatypes, any help would be appreciated:

```
Query error:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
```

Comment: where is your code? where is your data samples?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues to address here.

1. For the data type you can use TEXT, BLOB or any of the variations from this link according to the data size. Refer
   [MYSQL Documentation on TEXT and BLOB data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)
2. If you are trying to save HTML content to the database, then most probably your SQL generated is getting incorrect values due to the quotes `'` and double quotes `"` in the string.

**This would solve the issue.** 
You have to use parameters to pass the data.

```
String htmlValue = "<html> <....... ";

String sql = "insert into my_table (html_content) values( ? )";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement( sql );
stmt.setString( 1, htmlValue );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```